# Starndardized beta coefs through scale() funciton in Linear Regression with continuous and categorical independent variables

Tags: r, regression-coefficients

I have a memory task dataset composed of 3 variables: ctp, a measure of memory recall from my target (learned) stimulus, ctm, a measure of how much the same memory recall happens to a similar (but not the same) stimlus, over 10 days(categorical). Stimulus was not parametrized, physical differences between stimuli is fixed throughout the task.

This gives me the following dataframe in R.

```
cv <- data.frame(ctm, ctp, day)
str(cv)
#'data.frame':  860 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ ctm: num  1.667 2.083 1.667 1.667 0.417 ...
# $ ctp: num  1.25 0.833 3.333 1.25 2.5 ...
# $ day: Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I want to assess how much of the "false recall" or memory generalization can be predicted by the memory performance of the correct recall. And I want to see if that relationship changes over days, as the subject learns to discriminate the target and similar stimuli.
I so far have the model below

```
options(contrasts = c('contr.sum', 'contr.poly'))
m1 <- lm(ctm ~ ctp*day, data = cv)

> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = ctm ~ ctp * day, data = cv)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-46.724  -9.948  -2.027   9.807  56.847 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.81668    1.39250   2.023 0.043416 *  
ctp          0.43621    0.04342  10.046  < 2e-16 ***
day1         9.61044    2.92042   3.291 0.001041 ** 
day2         4.69763    3.37522   1.392 0.164352    
day3        -3.74516    3.75570  -0.997 0.318958    
day4        -4.14882    4.44419  -0.934 0.350811    
day5        -5.49235    5.08006  -1.081 0.279937    
day6        -2.71586    4.53893  -0.598 0.549768    
day7        -2.62319    4.59420  -0.571 0.568166    
day8         1.96173    4.52321   0.434 0.664616    
day9         0.17189    5.15888   0.033 0.973428    
ctp:day1    -0.06832    0.11580  -0.590 0.555369    
ctp:day2     0.15876    0.08108   1.958 0.050539 .  
ctp:day3     0.30262    0.07613   3.975 7.64e-05 ***
ctp:day4     0.19769    0.08051   2.456 0.014264 *  
ctp:day5     0.18341    0.08709   2.106 0.035503 *  
ctp:day6     0.05011    0.08287   0.605 0.545543    
ctp:day7     0.09535    0.08401   1.135 0.256709    
ctp:day8     0.01843    0.08516   0.216 0.828678    
ctp:day9    -0.33164    0.09179  -3.613 0.000321 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 17.04 on 840 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.47, Adjusted R-squared:  0.458 
F-statistic: 39.21 on 19 and 840 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I want to get both standardized and un-standardized coefficients for my model. I want the standardized coefficients because it is considered an effect size.

To get standardized coefficients, I have seen people using `scale()` in all variables. But that is a problem, I cannot do `lm(scale(ctm) ~ scale(ctp)*scale(day), data = cv)` because day is a categorical variable.

The `lm.beta()` function often used does not work on models that include interactions.
I have not found any other way to generate standardized beta values in a model with interaction between a continuous and a categorical variable.

Is there any better way of getting standardized coefficients?

Comment: Please say more about why you want coefficients for standardized predictors. They will be very dependent on the specifics of your data sample and hard to apply to new data samples. Please provide that information by editing your question, as comments are sometimes missed by visitors to this site and can even be lost.

Comment: Ultimately we likely will have to figure out whether you need something like `lm(scale(ctm) ~ 0 + scale(ctp)*scale(day),...)` or `lm(scale(ctm) ~ 0 + scale(ctp) + scale(day) + scale(I(scale(ctp)*scale(day)),...)` and you need to include a little more context or explanation in this post to help choose among these possible solutions.

Comment: @whuber You touched the very heart of it, from the approach I've been taking. What additional context do you need?

Comment: Some response to the questions posed by @EdM would help.